# 1st year University, reduced row echelon form

Tags: matrices

[Can someone explain me how each of these are incorrect answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKanE.png)

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: As far as I can see, **all of them** are in reduced echelon form. By the given answer though I think they meant by that "Reduced **Canonical** form"...

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes and votes to close if you edit the question to show what you have done so far and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

For a matrix to be in Row Echelon form, it must satisfy the following properties:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\bullet \text{ All nonzero rows are above any rows of all zeros.}\\
&\bullet \text{ Each leading entry of a row is in a column to the right of the leading entry of
the row above it.}\\
&\bullet \text{ All entries in a column below a leading entry are zeros.}\end{aligned}$$
And, to be in Row Reduced Echelon Form, it must satisfy the previous properties with the following:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\bullet \text{ The leading entry in each nonzero row is 1.}\\
&\bullet \text{ Each leading 1 is the only nonzero entry in its column.}
\end{aligned}
$$
Examle:
$$1.\, \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 3 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)\qquad \qquad 2.\, \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$1$ is in *Row Echelon Form*, while $2$ is in *Row Reduced Echelon Form*.

Now applying the above properties to your question you can see that:

$$\begin{aligned}
&-(a)\, \text{is not in RREF because there is a 5 above the pivot on the second row} \\
&-(b)\, \text{is not in RREF because there is a 5 above the pivot on the third row} \\ 
&-(c)\, \text{is not in RREF because there is a 1 above the pivot on the fourth row} \\
&-(e)\, \text{if you swap the last row with the second row, then it is in RREF} \\
\end{aligned}$$
This concludes that $(d)\, $ is the only matrix in $\text{RREF}$.

Comment: You might define “row echelon form” (the first three properties) and then add the conditions for “reduced row echelon form”.

Comment: @egreg will do!

Comment: Oh, and it's *echelon*, not *echolon*.